# How to change an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, logging, decorator

So my task is: Write a decorator that logs information about calls of decorated functions, the values of its arguments, keyword arguments, and execution time. The log should be written to a file.

My solution is:

```
``
from time import time

def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time() - start_time
        with open('log.txt', 'a+') as file:
            file.write(f'{func.__name__}; args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}, execution time: {end_time}\n sec.')
    return wrapper
``
```

I have to test it with  a function:

```
``
@log
def foo(a, b, c):
    ...

foo(1, 2, c=3)
``
```

And expected outcome in log.txt file must look something like this:

```
...
foo; args: a=1, b=2; kwargs: c=3; execution time: 0.12 sec.
...
```

But what I get is:

```
some_fun; args: (1, 2), kwargs: {'c': 3}, execution time: 0.0
sec.
```

How should I change my code to get an expected outcome?

---

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) from the `inspect` module (standard library) to fetch the variable names, and then use some string manipulations to get the desired output:

```py
from inspect import signature
from time import perf_counter

def log(func):
    params = signature(func).parameters.keys()
    logmsg = func.__name__ + "; args: {}; kwargs: {}; execution time: {} sec.\n"
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        extime = perf_counter() - start_time
        with open("log.txt", "a+") as file:
            args = ", ".join(f"{name}={value}" for name, value in zip(params, args))
            kwargs = ", ".join(f"{name}={value}" for name, value in kwargs.items())
            file.write(logmsg.format(args, kwargs, extime))
    return wrapper
```

[`perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) is better for performance measurement.

(In case you're not aware: Your wrapper builds a function that only returns `None`. If `func` returns something that the wrapped `func` should also return, then use `result = func(*args, **kwargs)` and do `return result` at the end.)

As pointed out by **@zvone**: This doesn't capture default arguments. If that is a concern, then you could use the following adjustment (which makes it a bit more complicated):

```py
from inspect import signature
from time import perf_counter

def log(func):
    sig = signature(func)
    logmsg = func.__name__ + "; args: {}; kwargs: {}; execution time: {} sec.\n"
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        extime = perf_counter() - start_time
        with open("log.txt", "a+") as file:
            binds = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            binds.apply_defaults()
            pairs = list(binds.arguments.items())
            args_str = ", ".join(f"{n}={v}" for n, v in pairs[:len(args)])
            kwargs_str = ", ".join(f"{n}={v}" for n, v in pairs[len(args):])
            file.write(logmsg.format(args_str, kwargs_str, extime))
    return wrapper
```

Here the default arguments that aren't given in `args` or `kwargs` get added to `kwargs` with their default value (only for the purpose of logging).

Comment: Good approach, but it seems like it won't be correct for every possible call to the function, taking care of default argument values. Using [Signature.bind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind) would be better.

Comment: @zvone Thanks for pointing that out! I've added a version that should fix it. Not sure if it is optimal, though.